# Comparing mergeinfo property between branch trunk using shell

Tags: linux, svn

Is there a way to use svn CLI to extract and compare mergeinfo property for any open branches to verify they have the latest from trunk? Was planning on automating this theory using shell

Answer (score 1):

You can use the option `--show-revs eligible` with the command `svn mergeinfo` to see, if there are any unmerged commits. See the documentation on the command *mergeinfo* for more information:

- http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.mergeinfo.html